# Python- Full screen nogui?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I made a program in python which allows you to type commands (e.g: if you type clock, it shows you the date and time). But, I want it to be fullscreen. The problem is that my software doesnt have gui and I dont want it to so that probably means that I wont be using tkinter or pygame. Can some of you write a whole 'hello world' program in fullscreen for me? What I am aiming for is for my program to look a bit like ms-dos. Any help??? By the way, im very new to python (approximately 4 weeks).

NOTE: I have python 3.4.1

Comment: The command prompt screen is not python but your OS.

Answer (score 1):

Since Vista, cmd.exe can no longer go to full-screen mode. You'll need to implement a full-screen console emulator yourself or look for another existing solution. E.g. [ConEmu](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/conemuthewindowsterminalconsolepromptwevebeenwaitingfor.aspx) appears to be able to do it.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

Use your Operating System services to configure parameters.

```
<_aMouseRightClick_>->[Properties]->[Layout]
```

Kindly notice, that some of the `python` interpreter process window parameters are given in [char]-s, while some other in [px]:

```
size.Width [char]-s
size.Height[char]-s
loc.X      [px]
loc.Y      [px]
```

So adjust these values so as to please your intentions.

[image: Settings before pseudo-FullScreenMode...]

You may set negative values for `[loc.X, loc.Y]` to move/hide window edges "outside" the screen left/top edges

Comment: Right, the emulators you refer to are on a deeper look also as just a window-wrapped emulated text screens :) so what exactly do you propose by this comment, Ivan? ... hmmm, Ivan's comment has just been deleted. funny